# Calculating transformation from origin to point

Tags: transformation, 3d, rotations, rigid-transformation

I have an icosahedron of radius $x$ with 12 vertices at known coordinates. If I have a point at $(0,0,x)$ where $x > 0$ and a vertex of this icosahedron at $(a,b,c)$ how can I find the rotation matrix between the two points?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose two vectors $u$ and $v$ that together with $w=(a,b,c)^\mathrm{T}/x$ form an orthonormal basis. The let $$R = \left[\array{u^\mathrm{T}\\v^\mathrm{T}\\w^\mathrm{T}}\right].$$ This gives a "rotation matrix" (orthogonal matrix) that maps $(a,b,c)^\mathrm{T}$ to $(0,0,x)^\mathrm{T}$ as you wanted. This matrix is not unique and varies by the orthonormal basis you choose.

Comment: I guess in this situation as my starting vector is $(0,0,x)$ I can chose any $u^T$ and $v^T$?

Comment: If $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal to each other and also orthogonal to $w$, then yes. So you can start by choosing $u$ to be a unit vector orthogonal to $w$, then you can determine $v$ as a unit vector orthogonal to both $u$ and $w$.

Comment: My thought was that as $(0,0,x) . R = [w_1x,w_2x,w_3x]$ meaning that $w_1 = \frac{a}{x} w_2 = \frac{b}{x}$ and  $w_3 = \frac{c}{x}$ so $u^T$ and $v^T$ could in theory be the same vector or any vector as long as those $w_i$ components are as above, it will be the rotation matrix from $(0,0,x)$ to $(a,b,c)$. Is my thought process correct? thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand the reasoning. (Also did you mean $R$ to be the rotation matrix? If so what you written is a vector not a matrix.) The point is we want to find a matrix $R$ such that $R(a,b,c)^\mathrm{T} = (0,0,x)^\mathrm{T}$. So the first and second rows of $R$ must be orthogonal to $(a,b,c)^\mathrm{T}$. Furthermore, inner product of the third row of $R$ and $(a,b,c)^\mathrm{T}$ must be equal to $x$ which is the norm of $(a,b,c)$. This happens only of the third row is $w$ that I chose. So $u$ and $v$ must be orthogonal to $w$ as well as each other. You have to normalize them as well.